# Setting whole doc and a specific value with one action mongoDB / meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

At present I'm doing this to update a Collection whenever a webhook is fired indicating changed object data:

```
Products.update( {id: shopifyID }, { $set: doc });
Products.update( {id: shopifyID }, { $set: { lowestPrice: lowestPriceVariant(doc) }});
```

However, I'm trying to achieve that with just one `update` call. The first is setting the object to whatever object is returned by a webhook, which is why there is no mapping of key/value. Is this possible with mongoDB? So far, any combination I have tried only updates `lowestPrice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
doc.lowestPrice = lowestPriceVariant(doc);
Products.update( {id: shopifyID }, { $set: doc });
```